# Rerun Firefox addon's script on URL dynamic change

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

To simplify the scenario, lets say I'm working on an extension that just contains: `alert("Hello")` whenever you load a page in example.com. Relevant manifest.json part:

```
"content_scripts": 
        [
            {
            "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"],
            "js": ["script.js"]
            }
        ]
```

When I first visit the website, it works fine. But the problem is some of the links in the website don't reload the page, they just manipulate the DOM. So a link for example will take you to example.com/foo, the script doesn't run. Even when I return to the home page, it doesn't run again, and all the edits that were made the first time are removed.

How do I make the add-on recognize that the page has changed, and rerun the script?

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours on this, I was finally able to achieve what I want, though not in the way I expected it would be. This is my solution:

```
 document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    editStuff();
});
```

This works just fine for the website I'm making the add-on for. There is some wasted computational power, as some clicks don't really require the function to work again, but its minimal in my use case.